# Nameless variable declaration - why does it work?

Tags: java, loops, object, for-loop

I am surprised to see this behaviour.

Is it a bug or something?

```
for(Object obj = new Object(), Integer = new Integer(300);
    obj.toString().length()>3;
    System.out.println("on object's loop")) {

} //causes an infinite loop (not foreach loop, of course)
```

above code compiles and run fine without any reference to `new Integer(300)`. Why so?

I am only interested in knowing  why `Integer = new Integer(300);` is okay without any reference.

Comment: It declares a new variable named `Integer` of type `Object` with initial value "a fresh `java.lang.Integer`, value 300". What's your   question?

Comment: Reopened -- It's a legitimate question (if perhaps poorly worded).  (Might be wise for the OP to rephrase the title.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Object obj = new Object(), Integer = new Integer(300);
```

This creates two variables:

1. **`obj`** of type `Object`, which gets assigned to `new Object()`.
2. **`Integer`** (yes, that's the *name* of the variable) *also* of type `Object`, which gets assigned to `new Integer(300)`.

By the way this has nothing to do with the `for`-loop; that line would compile fine on its own. Now, if that `,` was really a `;`, it would be a different story.

In general, we can construct valid statements of the form:

```
Type t1 = ..., t2 = ..., t3 = ..., ...;
```

which is equivalent to

```
Type t1 = ...;
Type t2 = ...;
Type t3 = ...;
...
```

Comment: Ah!  Because of the comma, "Integer" is interpreted as a variable name of type "Object".  (I've never been real fond of comma-extended declarations, since they create all sorts of opportunities for error/confusion.)

Comment: And using Integer as identifier, having these two together confused alot.

Comment: Since `Integer` is not a Java reserved keyword (as contrary to `int`), it can be used as variable name.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: You are correct, as I said, it was confusing.

Comment: @Nambari yes it was =\ but when copying pasting the code in your fav IDE (eclipse, netbeans, intellij or whatever) you will find that it works fine and probably freak out for not noticing something that simple (happened to me =S)

Answer (score 15):

> I think he's asking why Integer = new Integer(300) works. – arshajii 2 mins ago

`Integer` is valid identifier name and its type is `Object` because of

```
Object obj = new Object(), Integer = new Integer(300);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
int a=2, b=4;
```

`obj.toString()` prints the `String` (consisting classname and hashcode), which has length > 3 so the infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

```
    String String = "foo";
    System.out.println(new String(String));
```

is also legal - the compiler is clever enough to figure out which is a variable reference and which is not.